# Problema com API Laravel em produção

Tags: laravel, api, deploy

Fiz um deploy de uma API em laravel. O problema que está ocorrendo é o seguinte: a API online sempre me retorna '200 ok', sem chegar ao menos ao controller de login. Com essa mesma API, fiz o teste em localhost e funcionou. Preciso definir mais alguma permissão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Seria interessante **posta o código** do método do seu **controller**, pois dependendo das condições utilizadas ele pode está passando no método sem efetuar nenhuma operação, até chegar no return, por isso está dando 200.

Ex:

```
{
   $dados = (object) $request->all();
   $usuario = usuairo::where('email',$dados->email)->first();
   if($usuario){
      if($this->testeUsuarioSenha($dados))
         return Response::json(['message' => 'Login realizado com sucesso'], 200);
      else
         return Response::json(['message' => 'Não encontrado'], 404);
   } 
   return '';

}
```

Analisando o código acima, concorda que para emails que não existem na base vai retornar http 200? Emfim para ajudar precisaria de mais informações.

No servidor execute o seguinte comando e analise suas rotas:

`php artisan route:list`

Outro ponto interessante a se observar, é em produção rodar também.

```
    php artisan route:cache
```